# JACK Issue with Internet DJ Console in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, streaming

Running jack in dummy mode gives no audio from Internet DJ Console but the stream played from the server works perfectly fine. You can tune into the stream at http://myradiostream.com/olpr

The server is a shoutcast server with the following settings.

```
Server address: s18.myradiostream.com
Port: 4362
Bitrate: 128kbps
```

The output from running jack in terminal looks like this...

```
jeremy@Zeus:~$ jackd -d dummy -r 44100
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 18 port_dst = 28
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 19 port_dst = 29
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 20 port_dst = 30
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 21 port_dst = 31
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 22 port_dst = 32
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 23 port_dst = 33
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 24 port_dst = 34
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 26 port_dst = 34
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 25 port_dst = 35
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 27 port_dst = 35
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 11 port_dst = 37
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 12 port_dst = 38
```

The problem is that you can run jack like this too and get audio on the computer, but not in the stream. When you run it like this the audio on the computer is crystal clear. The stream however shows the song name and online status, but you hear nothing at all.

```
jeremy@Zeus:~$ jackd -d alsa
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 18 port_dst = 28
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 19 port_dst = 29
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 20 port_dst = 30
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 21 port_dst = 31
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 22 port_dst = 32
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 23 port_dst = 33
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 24 port_dst = 34
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 26 port_dst = 34
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 25 port_dst = 35
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 27 port_dst = 35
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 11 port_dst = 37
JackGraphManager::Connect already connected port_src = 12 port_dst = 38
```

Please help me with this. I've been pouring over manuals for the last week and came up with the stark realization that I'm no audio engineer.

Thanks in advance Ubuntu geniuses! :)

Also, addendum. Restarting the computer leaves IDJC with crackling audio and no sound on the stream.

**UPDATE**

I installed Patchage to view my connections and it would appear that I am routing just fine to the speakers but the stream is failing to receive audio. Its like the volume is turned down on the stream but the rest of the information streams over perfectly fine. People can see my DJ name and information about the track and online status. They simply hear nothing!

What am I missing here in order to get audio to the stream?

I would post images but this website is preventing me from doing so citing that I have too low of a reputation points score or something.

**UPDATE 2**

I just installed all this on a 32 bit tower and it failed in the exact same way.

**UPDATE 3**

I GOT IT TO WORK IN THE STREAM!

Problem is I'm not too sure how I did it. I installed a bunch of Ubuntu Studio metapackages and then purged everything from my system and reinstalled IDJC. Its working now so I'll take it. If anyone else sees this and needs similar help just keep working at it and you'll do great! I promise!

Comment: Did you try to connect the IDJC ports to the ALSA ports?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that I suppose. I have qjackctl running and its got a connection button but I left it alone because I don't really know what I'm doing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To route the IDJC output to the speakers, use a tool such as QjackCtl to make a connection from the IDJC output ports to the ALSA speaker ports:
[image: QjackCtl audio connections]

Comment: I simply don't understand where those are. Please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something. I don't have alsa_pcm showing in that list. I see three tabs at the top: audio, midi, and alsa. Under audio I have idjc_default with several connections and system. The alsa tab just shows an unconnected MIDI slot. I suppose the question is how can I make that appear...

Comment: I got something new to show up by messing with this tutorial and creating a .asoundrc file in my home folder. http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc Still haven't gotten it working on the stream yet but we're getting closer.